# clear everything but one variable rm(list = ls())

Tags: r

I'm aware that `rm(list = ls())` will clear my workspace.

I have a data frame x that I would like to preserve while removing everything else from memory. How can I do that?

```
rm(list = ls(!x)) #???
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try: `rm(list = setdiff(ls(), x))`

Edit based on mickey's comment:

Three objects in environment:

```
ls()
[1] "data_df" "list_ls" "vector_v"
```

Remove data_df:

```
rm(list = setdiff(ls(), "data_df"))
ls()
[1] "data_df"
```

Vector of things to keep:

```
toKeep_v <- c("list_ls", "vector_v")
rm(list = setdiff(ls(), toKeep_v)
ls()
[1] "list_ls" "vector_v"
```

Comment: If x is the name of the data frame, it should be in quotes.

Comment: While `rm` has NSE, `setdiff` doesn't so this will have unexpected results unless `x` is `"x"`